# May a US citizen fly a US ultralight into Canada?

Tags: regulations, ultralight, transport-canada

May a US citizen (no pilot license) fly a US ultralight into Canada or any other country?

Due to a special exemption, Canadian pilots may fly a basic ultralight (registered but no certificate of airworthiness) into the US.

I don't think a US ultralight may be flown into Canada or any other country as it is not registered and does not have a certificate of airworthiness.  Is this true?

Comment: Unless you add the phrase "legally" or "in compliance with regulations", the answer has to be "yes"!

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question!

Ultralights can be registered with the EAA's vehicle registration program, which issues a registration ID beginning with the letter "E". The problem is that in Canada you need a license to operate the aircraft. That is why there is no reciprocation between the US and Canada for that special exemption rule. In Canada, ultralight pilots are required to have a license. If you have a US pilot's license from Recreational on up, and an "E" registered ultralight, you are compliant with Canada's requirements. From [Transport Canada's website](https://tc.canada.ca/en/aviation/licensing-pilots-personnel/flight-crew-licences-permits-ratings/licensing-foreign-pilots):

> Foreign licence validation certificate (for recreational pilots)
>
> Visitors to Canada may have a foreign pilot licence validated for
> private recreational purposes. The foreign pilot licence must be
> valid:
>
> - under the law of the issuing state
> - and for privileges appropriate to the reason you’re flying
>
> You may apply for a foreign licence validation certificate before
> arriving in Canada. The certificate will be issued for a period of one
> year. After a year you may renew it or apply for a permanent Canadian
> pilot licence.
>
> To learn more about the certificate, including how to apply, read
> [Advisory Circular 400-003: Foreign Licence Validation
> Certificate.](https://tc.canada.ca/sites/default/files/migrated/ac_400_003.pdf)

To my knowledge, no other country has the same type of ultralight aircraft rules as the US.

Comment: @StephenS Canadian ultralight licenses are actually permits and not ICAO compliant either. But that's not relevant to Canada and the US; if they accept each other's permits then there's no issue. ICAO does not enforce license requirements, individual countries do.

Comment: That is incorrect. It varies from country to country. I have updated my answer with more relevant info about this. You can use a Rec Pilot license in Canada if it is validated.

Comment: Sec 4.0(2) does not support your claim that a license lower than Private can be validated.

Comment: @StephenS Neither does it say that it can't be. It says "private recreational purposes."

Comment: That doc lists 7 specific license types that can be validated, and the lowest is Private.